# CLR Debugger for .Net 4.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, .net-4.0

After moving to .Net Framework 4.0,
I have tried to use my usual tool CLR debugger which comes with SDK 2.0 on client servers that doesn't have VS2010 installation (or any other IDE installed).
Unfortunately CLR debugger didn't worked :(.
I didn't find any SDK for .Net 4.0, is there any alternative debugging tool for v4.0?

Update: 
May be i need to install VS2010 express on those machines?

[post about it at www.devartplus.com](http://www.devartplus.com/csharp/net-framework-4-0-and-vs2010-things-that-i-dont-like/)

Update: Official microsoft answer - They doesn't support CLR debugger any more.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned one option is WinDbg which can debug almost anything though you'll need some extensions (SOS / SOSEX) to debug managed code. Not only is WinDbg very powerful but it also doesn't need to be installed (i.e. can be started directly from a USB stick).

Another good option if you are debugging some crashes or strange behaviour that happen at some point is to generate dump files which can be later analysed in WinDbg (or VS2010). You can manually generate those (by right clicking the process in the task manager and selecting the option to generate a mini-dump) or use some tool that automates the process (search for adplus or procdump for example).

Comment: WinDbg is always an option, but it's not that nice as see the source code and have IDE (like it is in CLR debugger).

Answer (score 1):

WinDbg is a text based debugger similar to GDB. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009

However, I do wonder why you don't setup remote debugging on those machines and enable it as needed?

Comment: 10x for quick reply! Remote debugger its not an option - those servers are at client site and we do not have any permissions to connect there remotely.

Comment: @user3072 - Well, if you can debug onsite, then I think you try convincing your customer that installing remote debugging and allowing _on-site_ remote debugging is the fastest and most future-proof way of fixing problems. Good luck!